# Node.js How to pass Ajax success message to app.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, node.js

`Node.js` how to pass `Ajax` success message to `app.js`, because i need to know user Log-in status

ex:If user have not logged in, redirect to `log-in.html`, so I need to know success message.

**index.html**

```
...
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>

            $.ajax({
                url: URLs,
                data: $('#sentToBack').serialize(),
                type:"POST",
                dataType:'text',

                success: function(msg){
                   if(msg == "True")
                   {
                     location.href = '/index.html';
                   }

                },

                 error:function(msg){ 
                    console.log(msg);
                 }
            });

</script>
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // I want to send to here !!
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: To send something to _app.js_ (server) you need to make another AJAX call. Also, why don't you redirect to _log-in.html_ in the _success_ / _error_ callback itself using something like `location.href`

Comment: @Sourabh- Thanks for your answer!! If someone move into 'index.html', it will ignore logging action !

Answer (score 0):

There are *many* different ways to do this.

This here

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // I want to send to here !!
});
```

is defining the function that will *handle get requests to your root route*.

If you are sending AJAX requests, you need to think about what METHOD (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) you are using, and what CONTENT you are sending.  You may need something to parse the body if you are, for example, using JSON.

If you want to maintain session information and logins etc, I would suggest looking into some [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html) like [PassportJS](http://passportjs.org/).

You can configure `Passport` to automatically redirect to the login page whenever a request is received from an unauthenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare a post ressource with express and enable the body parser

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.post('/yourRessource', function(req, res) {
  var sendToBack = req.body;
  console.log(sendToBack); // debugging
});
```